# Finding equations for projective curves, low genus, Riemann-Roch.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $C \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a nonsingular projective curve, and let $L \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a hyperplane. We have that $L \cdot C$ is a divisor $H$ on $C$ if $C \subset L$. Let $R = \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty L(kH)$; this is a graded algebra. We have a homomorphism $\alpha$ of graded algebras that maps $\mathbb{C}[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ to the right hand side of the equation. We have that $\alpha$ is surjective.

When $g = 1$ ($C \subset \mathbb{CP}^2$ is a nonsingular cubic), I find that $\ell(kH) = 3k$ and $\text{dim}\, V_k = \text{dim}\ \mathbb{C}[x_0, x_1, x_2]_k = \binom{k+2}{k}$. What is $\ell(kH)$ and $\text{dim}\,V_k$ for $g = 2$? For such a seemingly fundamental result I can't find a reference anywhere online...

Comment: It depends on the embedding. All you can say without knowing the embedding is that by RR, $\ell(D)=\mathrm{deg}(D)-1$ as soon as $\mathrm{deg}(D) \geq 3$. Actually, I think that any very ample $D$ has degree at least $5$, so presumably it just depends on the degree of the embedding.